# JQLParseException: Cannot execute JQL query in ScriptRunner to print number of issues having a specific value for the summary field

Tags: groovy, jira, atlassian-sourcetree, jql, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am trying to execute some code in script runner to know how many issues have a certain value as a summary. The code should be super easy and straightforward but I am running into a `JQLParseException`. I am looking for all issues with value "aa" for the summary field. I am getting this exception in the log file:

```
2022-08-05 15:18:52,115+0200 https-openssl-nio-443-exec-22 WARN mouh 918x48846x1 19eejnp 10.248.75.214 /secure/CommentAssignIssue.jspa [atlassian-jira.log] myyy exception: com.atlassian.jira.jql.parser.JqlParseException: com.atlassian.jira.jql.parser.antlr.RuntimeRecognitionException: NoViableAltException(59@[])
```

I also executed the query in `Jira` and it returns 274 results so it should work
[image]
Here is my code

```
   import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
import com.opensymphony.workflow.InvalidInputException;
import com.softwareag.jira.insight.helper.Helper;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Map;
import com.atlassian.jira.project.version.Version;
import com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.issue.AbstractJiraFunctionProvider;
import com.opensymphony.module.propertyset.PropertySet;
import com.opensymphony.workflow.WorkflowException;
import groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult
import groovy.sql.*
import groovy.sql.Sql
import java.sql.*; 
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.ofbiz.core.entity.ConnectionFactory;
import org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericEntityException;
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchProvider
import com.atlassian.jira.jql.parser.JqlQueryParser
import com.atlassian.jira.web.bean.PagerFilter


log.warn("HELLO 111")       

def log = Logger.getLogger("atlassian-jira.log")










def jqlQueryParser = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(JqlQueryParser)
log.warn("MOUNA 3 ")
def searchProvider = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(SearchProvider)
log.warn("MOUNA 4 ")

def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()
log.warn("MOUNA 5")




// edit this query to suit
// I am looking for all issues with value "aa" for the summary field
def myquery = "summary ~ aa" 
log.warn("total issues  "+ myquery)

try{
def query = jqlQueryParser.parseQuery(myquery)

}catch (Exception e){
    log.warn("myyy exception: "+e)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it should be like this

`def query = jqlQueryParser.parseQuery("summary ~ \'" + customDiagnoserId + "\'")`

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping your summary string in single quotes `'` should fix this.

`def myquery = "summary ~ 'aa'"`

Comment: the backslashes are needed   def query = jqlQueryParser.parseQuery("summary ~ \'" + customDiagnoserId + "\'")